# Dropdown error in Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I created dropdown list as in bootstrap 4 documentation [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/]
But when I click the button It gives the error which is in below.

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage Recipe</button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">To Shopping List</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Edit Recipe</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Delete Recipe</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: It says need propper.js]

But I've already installed propper.js dependency. And also I used another dropdown list in nav bar and collapse but they work fine.

This is the code in angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
   "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
 ],
```

Comment: Check the order.. it should be jquery, then popper, then bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies should be imported *before* Bootstrap itself, because the latter will try to use functions from Popper or jQuery that has not been imported yet. So you'll have to place `popper.min.js` *before* bootstrap:

```
...
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
   "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```